# Embedding python Matplotlib Graph in html using Pyscript

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyscript

I've written a python program that takes some inputs and turns them into a matplotlib graph. Specifically, it displays wealth distributions by percentile for a country of the user's choosing. However, these inputs are currently given by changing variables in the program.

I want to put this code on a website, allowing users to choose any country and see the wealth distribution for that country, as well as how they compare. Essentially, I am trying to recreate this: https://wid.world/income-comparator/

The code in python is all done but I am struggling to incorporate it into an HTML file. I was trying to use pyscript but it currently loads forever and displays nothing. Would rather not rewrite it in javascript (mainly because I don't know js). My thoughts are that it has something to do with the code importing csv files from my device?

```
import csv
from typing import List
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import collections
import math
from forex_python.converter import CurrencyRates


# ---------------- #


# whether or not the graph includes the top 1 percent in the graph (makes the rest of the graph visible!)
one_percent = False # True or False

# pick which country(ies) you want to view
country = 'China' # String

# what currency should the graph use
currency_used = 'Canada' # String

# if you want to compare an income
compare_income = True # True or False

# what income do you want to compare
income = 100000 # Int
 

# ---------------- #

codes = {}

# get dictionary of monetary country codes
monetary_codes = {}
with open('codes-all.csv') as csv_file:
    list = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',') 
    for row in list:
        if row[5] == "":
            monetary_codes[row[0]] = (row[2], row[1])

# get dictionary of country names and codes for WID
with open('WID_countries.csv') as csv_file:
    WID_codes = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',') 
    next(WID_codes)

    for row in WID_codes:

        if len(row[0]) == 2:
            if row[2] != "":
                monetary_code = monetary_codes[row[1].upper()][0]
                currency_name = monetary_codes[row[1].upper()][1]
                codes[row[1].upper()] = (row[0], monetary_code, currency_name)
            elif row[2] == "":
                codes[row[1].upper()] = (row[0], 'USD', 'United States Dollar')

        elif row[0][0] == 'U' and row[0][1] == 'S':
            codes[row[1].upper()] = (row[0], 'USD', 'United States Dollar')


# converts user input to upper case
country = country.upper()
currency_used = currency_used.upper()

# gets conversion rate
c = CurrencyRates()
conversion_rate = c.get_rate(codes[country][1], codes[currency_used][1])


# convert money into correct currency
def convert_money(conversion_rate, value):
    return float(value) * conversion_rate


# get and clean data    
def get_data(country):

    aptinc = {}

    # cleaning the data
    with open(f'country_data/WID_data_{codes[country][0]}.csv') as csv_file:
        data = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=';') 

        for row in data:

            # I only care about the year 2021 and the variable 'aptinc'
            if 'aptinc992' in row[1] and row[3] == '2021':

                # translates percentile string into a numerical value
                index = 0
                for i in row[2]:

                    # index 0 is always 'p', so we get rid of that
                    if index == 0:
                        row[2] = row[2][1:]

                    # each string has a p in the middle of the numbers we care about. I also only 
                    # care about the rows which measure a single percentile 
                    # (upper bound - lower bound <= 1)
                    elif i == 'p':
                        lb = float(row[2][:index - 1])
                        ub = float(row[2][index:])

                        # if the top one percent is being filtered out adds another requirement
                        if not one_percent:
                            if ub - lb <= 1 and ub <= 99: 
                                row[2] = ub
                            else: 
                                row[2] = 0
                        else:
                            if ub - lb <= 1:
                                row[2] = ub
                            else: row[2] = 0
                    index += 1

                # adds wanted, cleaned data to a dictionary. Also converts all values to one currency
                if row[2] != 0:                    
                    aptinc[row[2]] = convert_money(conversion_rate, row[4])

    return aptinc


# find the closest percentile to an income
def closest_percentile(income, data):
    closest = math.inf
    percentile = float()
    for i in data:
        difference = income - data[i]
        if abs(difference) < closest:
            closest = difference
            percentile = i
    return percentile


# ---------------- #


unsorted_data = {}
percentiles = []
average_income = []


# gets data for the country
data = get_data(country)
for i in data:
    unsorted_data[i] = data[i]


# sorts the data
sorted = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(unsorted_data.items()))
for i in sorted:
    percentiles.append(i)
    average_income.append(data[i])


# makes countries pretty for printing
country = country.lower()
country = country.capitalize()

# calculates where the income places against incomes from country(ies)
blurb = ""        
if compare_income:
    percentile = closest_percentile(income, sorted)
    blurb = f"You are richer than {round(percentile)} percent of {country}'s population"

# plot this data!
plt.plot(percentiles,average_income)
plt.title(f'{country} Average Annual Income by Percentile')
plt.xlabel(f'Percentile\n{blurb}')
plt.ylabel(f'Average Annual Income of {country}({codes[currency_used][1]})')
plt.axvline(x = 99, color = 'r', label = '99th percentile', linestyle=':')
if compare_income:
    plt.axvline(x = percentile, color = 'g', label = f'{income} {codes[currency_used][2]}')
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor = (0, 1), loc = 'upper left')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Why don't you just create a traditional web site to deliver this?  You can use the more powerful compute engine on your web server instead of relying on whatever hardware the user might have, and the Python processing is supported well-understood.  Pyscript is cool, but it's still running a simulation in Javascript in the browser, and that's never going to be fast.

Comment: Open the browser debugger. Edit your question with the error messages. I wrote almost 20 articles on PyScript including one on how to debug this type of problem: https://www.jhanley.com/category/pyscript/

Comment: @TimRoberts - PyScript is **not** running a simulation in JavaScript. CPython has been compiled to WASM and performance is very good compared to JavaScript.

Comment: Even so, if you're doing compute-intensive processing, that's always going to be better suited for a web server running on bare metal.